# python regex first/shortest match

Tags: python, regex

trying to write an regex that can find all patterns

```
p = "q=http://.*\.doc" in 

text = "q=http://11111.doc,q=http://22222.doc"
```

when I did finall on text,

I get the whole thing, i.e. `q=http://11111.doc,q=http://22222.doc`

but not `q=http://11111.doc` and `q=http://22222.doc`

how do I fix it?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

That's because `*` is a greedy quantifier, trying to match as much as it can. Make it `*?`:

```
q=http://.*?\.doc
```

More information can be found in the *Regular Expression HOWTO*:
 [Greedy versus Non-greedy](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy)