# Regular expression for removing text with parenthesis

Tags: python, python-re

Take this text for example `泣（な）き出（だ）した`, I want to remove the furigana programmatically (ie. `泣き出した`). I tried

```
re.sub(r"\（[^()]*\）", "", '泣（な）き出（だ）した')
```

but it returns `泣した` instead. What is the better regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try
`re.sub(r"\（.*?\）", "", '泣（な）き出（だ）した')`, which uses the [non-greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301387/python-regex-first-shortest-match) quantifier `*?`.

Comment: I don't see the point in having this `[^()]` character class then. Might as well just use `.`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen you're right, I just made a small modification on the original code. Will edit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The parentheses in your character class are half-width (半角) instead of full-width (全角) parentheses.

Replacing them will fix your problem:

```
import re

re.sub(r"\（[^（）]*\）", "", '泣（な）き出（だ）した')

# '泣き出した'
```

Comment: Thanks but I want the solution that includes half width characters. Does it exist?

Comment: So you also have input where the furigana are delimited with half-width parentheses, is that what you're saying?